# Accessing nested objects in JSON undefinded error

Tags: json, knockout.js

i get error on console--[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZgrv.png)
app.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

i am trying to access the property 
data.places.geomtry.location.lat

```
 var initialPlaces = {
        "places":
        [{
            "geometry" : {
                "location" :{
                    "lat" : "40.715813",
                    "lng" : "-74.009433"
                }   
            },
            "name" : "Acappella"
        },{
            "geometry" : {
                "location" :{ 
                    "lat" : "40.715813",
                    "lng" : "-74.009433"
                }   
            },
            "name" : "Acappella"
        }
        ]
    }

var Place = function(data){
   console.log(data);
   this.geometry.location.lat = ko.observable(data.geometry.location.lat);
   this.geometry.location.lng = ko.observable(data.geometry.location.lng);
   this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you are trying to get a property from a list, not from a object. If you see the console result return a list, not the object place. You Could do that:

```js
var initialPlaces = {
   "places": [{
     "geometry": {
       "location": {
         "lat": "40.715813",
         "lng": "-74.009433"
       }
     },
     "name": "Acappella"
   }, {
     "geometry": {
       "location": {
         "lat": "40.715813",
         "lng": "-74.009433"
       }
     },
     "name": "Acappella"
   }]
 }

 var ViewModel = function() {

   var self = this;

   self.place = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialPlaces);
   
 };

 var viewModel = new ViewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: place.places">
  <li>
    <p data-bind="text:$data.name"></p>
    <p data-bind="text:$data.geometry.location.lat"></p>
    <p data-bind="text:$data.geometry.location.lng"></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[EDIT]**

Sorry, as you said you need a nested object so I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
var Place = function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   this.geometry.location.lat // <<
   ...
```

You first of all need to *create* the `geometry` object variable, then add a `location` property, and then finally add your observables to that.

```
var Place = function(data) {

   var self = this;

   self.geometry = {
      location: {
         lat: ko.observable(data.geometry.location.lat),
         lng: ko.observable(data.geometry.location.lng),
      }
   };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically ,the problem was that i was trying to acces an object that was not created - geometry

`this.geometry.location.lat`

So, I can only use

`this.lat = ko.observable(data.geometry.location.lat)`